# OLE DB exception "Class not registered" only when running Unit Test

Tags: c++, com, oledb, atl

I have a Windows based C++ application/library which uses Excel environment as interface. The library retrieves information from an Access database.

The C++ library classes are based on Active Template Library for COM.

When I run/debug the library, everything works fine. The class function responsible for retrieving data from the Access database though COM, has no problem setting up the connection.

But when I run a unit cases (Microsoft C++ Unit Testing Framework), it fails when reaching the function OpenFromInitializationString in atldbcli.h.

```
HRESULT OpenFromInitializationString(
                _In_z_ LPCOLESTR szInitializationString,
                _In_ bool fPromptForInfo = false) throw()
{
  CComPtr<IDataInitialize> spDataInit;

  HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(MSDAINITIALIZE), NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, __uuidof(IDataInitialize), (void**)&spDataInit);

  if (FAILED(hr))
    return hr;

  hr = spDataInit->GetDataSource(NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, szInitializationString, __uuidof(IDBInitialize), (IUnknown**)&m_spInit);

  if (FAILED(hr))
    return hr;
```

The latter call to GetDataSource fails, and returns "class not registered", when running the unit test. Same code succeeds when running or debbuging the whole application/library. **What is even more puzzling is that the same solution runs on my colleagues computer, both the unit test and the actual applicaiton/library.**

I'm running Windows 10 64-bit and Office 365 ProPlus. I have Visual Studio 2017 installed.

I would greatly appreciate if anyone would know what's going on. Keep these in mind.

- The unit tests are not within a separate project, but only a separate file on in the main project.
- Oledb32.dll is installed in following location C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\System\Ole DB\oledb32.dll (version 10.0.16299.15)

The szInitializationString looks like this in both cases:

```
L"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;User ID=Admin;Data Source = C:\\Repos\\Xerf\\XerfLib\\XerfData.accdb;Mode = Share Deny None;Extended Properties = \"\";Jet OLEDB:System database=\"\";Jet OLEDB:Registry Path=\"\";Jet OLEDB:Database Password=\"\";Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=6;Jet OLEDB:Database Locking Mode=1;Jet OLEDB:Global Partial Bulk Ops=2;Jet OLEDB:Global Bulk Transactions=1;Jet OLEDB:New Database Password=\"\";Jet OLEDB:Create System Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Encrypt Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Don't Copy Locale on Compact=False;Jet OLEDB:Compact Without Replica Repair=False;Jet OLEDB:SFP=False;Jet OLEDB:Support Complex Data=False;Jet OLEDB:Bypass UserInfo Validation=False;Jet OLEDB:Limited DB Caching=False;Jet OLEDB:Bypass ChoiceField Validation=False"
```

I have tried create a minimal project and it returns the same error. Here is the minimal code.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    WCHAR  m_DBInitializationString[1024]{};
    WCHAR  m_DatabasePath[_MAX_PATH]{};
    int iTmp;

    CDataSource db;
    HRESULT hr;

    CoInitialize(NULL);

    size_t wclen = (sizeof m_DBInitializationString) / (sizeof m_DBInitializationString[0]);
    wcscpy_s(m_DatabasePath, _MAX_PATH, L"C:\\Repos\\Xerf\\XerfLib\\XerfData.accdb");

    iTmp = swprintf_s(m_DBInitializationString, wclen, L"%s", L"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0;");
    iTmp += swprintf_s(&m_DBInitializationString[iTmp], wclen - iTmp, L"%s", L"User ID=Admin;");
    iTmp += swprintf_s(&m_DBInitializationString[iTmp], wclen - iTmp, L"Data Source = %s;", m_DatabasePath);
    iTmp += swprintf_s(&m_DBInitializationString[iTmp], wclen - iTmp, L"%s", L"Mode = Share Deny None;");
    iTmp += swprintf_s(&m_DBInitializationString[iTmp], wclen - iTmp, L"%s", L"Extended Properties = \"\";");
    iTmp += swprintf_s(&m_DBInitializationString[iTmp], wclen - iTmp, L"%s", L"Jet OLEDB:System database=\"\";");
    iTmp += swprintf_s(&m_DBInitializationString[iTmp], wclen - iTmp, L"%s", L"Jet OLEDB:Registry Path=\"\";");
    iTmp += swprintf_s(&m_DBInitializationString[iTmp], wclen - iTmp, L"%s", L"Jet OLEDB:Database Password=\"\";");
    iTmp += swprintf_s(&m_DBInitializationString[iTmp], wclen - iTmp, L"%s", L"Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=6;");
    iTmp += swprintf_s(&m_DBInitializationString[iTmp], wclen - iTmp, L"%s", L"Jet OLEDB:Database Locking Mode=1;");
    iTmp += swprintf_s(&m_DBInitializationString[iTmp], wclen - iTmp, L"%s", L"Jet OLEDB:Global Partial Bulk Ops=2;");
    iTmp += swprintf_s(&m_DBInitializationString[iTmp], wclen - iTmp, L"%s", L"Jet OLEDB:Global Bulk Transactions=1;");
    iTmp += swprintf_s(&m_DBInitializationString[iTmp], wclen - iTmp, L"%s", L"Jet OLEDB:New Database Password=\"\";");
    iTmp += swprintf_s(&m_DBInitializationString[iTmp], wclen - iTmp, L"%s", L"Jet OLEDB:Create System Database=False;");
    iTmp += swprintf_s(&m_DBInitializationString[iTmp], wclen - iTmp, L"%s", L"Jet OLEDB:Encrypt Database=False;");
    iTmp += swprintf_s(&m_DBInitializationString[iTmp], wclen - iTmp, L"%s", L"Jet OLEDB:Don't Copy Locale on Compact=False;");
    iTmp += swprintf_s(&m_DBInitializationString[iTmp], wclen - iTmp, L"%s", L"Jet OLEDB:Compact Without Replica Repair=False;");
    iTmp += swprintf_s(&m_DBInitializationString[iTmp], wclen - iTmp, L"%s", L"Jet OLEDB:SFP=False;");
    iTmp += swprintf_s(&m_DBInitializationString[iTmp], wclen - iTmp, L"%s", L"Jet OLEDB:Support Complex Data=False;");
    iTmp += swprintf_s(&m_DBInitializationString[iTmp], wclen - iTmp, L"%s", L"Jet OLEDB:Bypass UserInfo Validation=False;");
    iTmp += swprintf_s(&m_DBInitializationString[iTmp], wclen - iTmp, L"%s", L"Jet OLEDB:Limited DB Caching=False;");
    iTmp += swprintf_s(&m_DBInitializationString[iTmp], wclen - iTmp, L"%s", L"Jet OLEDB:Bypass ChoiceField Validation=False");

    hr = db.OpenFromInitializationString(m_DBInitializationString);

    return hr;
}
```

This code is included in the precompiled header stdafx.h

```
#pragma once

#ifndef STRICT
#define STRICT
#endif

#include "targetver.h"

#define m_dwRef                m_dwRefAtl
#define m_pOuterUnknown        m_pOuterUnknownAtl
#define InternalQueryInterface InternalQueryInterfaceAtl
#define InternalAddRef         InternalAddRefAtl
#define InternalRelease        InternalReleaseAtl

//#define _ATL_DEBUG_INTERFACES //Writes, to the output window, any interface leaks that are detected when _Module.Term is called.
//#define _ATL_DEBUG_QI         //Writes all calls to QueryInterface to the output window.
#define _ATL_APARTMENT_THREADED
#define _ATL_NO_AUTOMATIC_NAMESPACE
#define _ATL_CSTRING_EXPLICIT_CONSTRUCTORS  // some CString constructors will be explicit

//#define ATL_NO_ASSERT_ON_DESTROY_NONEXISTENT_WINDOW

#include <atlbase.h>
#include <atlcom.h>
#include <atlctl.h>
#include <AtlConv.h>

// DB access
#include <atldbcli.h>
#include <atldb.h>

using namespace ATL;
```

Best regards,
Johan

Comment: Are the application and unit tests compiled for the same bitness? You will get that error if you are running a 64-bit unit test, but have not registered the 64-bit version of the COM server.

Comment: @IInspectable It's all one solution and project, and the unit tests are just  a separate cpp file, being compiled together with the debug project. The application and unit test both use the same class and atl function. So both are 32-bit.

Comment: Do you have the same includes in both cpp files? Does the method have the same parameters when called in the cpp files? (szInitializationString)

Comment: You'll have to focus on the specific class that it is complaining about.  Easy to think that it is your own ATL class.  But it is not, it would not get this far and not crash here, it cannot find the OLEDB data provider.  We can't see the connection string you use.

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk The input parameter is exactly the same on both (szInitializationString). The header files are the same. When running/debugging the calls to the class come from Excel/VBA through COM. When running the unit test the call to the class and function is "direct".

Comment: How by COM? Only idea I have now is that the user rights are diffrent in test app and production app. (example a service is startup with diffrent rights than app)

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk Good comment. Added the connection string above.

Comment: Added important clue. Opening the same solution/project on other computers, the unit case runs just fine. Something is different on my computer, but can't figure out what.

Comment: The ACE provider is not available on a plain Windows install.  Either Office needs to be present or you have to use the ACE redist installer.

Comment: Try to me a minimal project of the app which is not working (not the unit tests).

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk I have ACEOLEDB.DLL installed at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\VFS\ProgramFilesCommonX86\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE16. So it is installed.

Comment: I think you meant to send that to Hans Passant. Please provide the code for a minimal project and a description how to create your "solution" in VS, which can be debugged.

Comment: @HansPassant  Thanks for the good ideas. I'm working on a minimal project but I've had some setbacks. However, I tried to install the Access 2016 redistributable 32-bit, but it fails with error that I would have Office 64-bit installed, although I have the 32-bit version installed.

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk For some reason after installing Microsoft Access 2013 Runtime 32-bit and after setting Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 in the m_DBInitializationString string, it works. It must be something wrong with the Office 2016 installtion (365 ProPlus). Although I could replicate the problem on a VM installing the same Office version.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an explanation, but it's solution to the problem.

Installing Microsoft Access 2013 Runtime 32-bit solves the problem.

Even if I specified earlier in the init string that `Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` it didn't have any affect, since the only ACE provider installed was the one belonging to Office 2016 suite.

I would be grateful for an explanation why the Office 2016 32-bit ACE provider didn't work.

Here's the minimal project https://github.com/jahlqvis/TestOLEDBAccess

Comment: Look in the registry under **HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT** for the class name (a.k.a. ProgID). On my machine, there is a registry key **HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0**, and I can load that provider (using your test program). I do not have **HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0** and using that ProgID (in the unmodified version of your program) I get the "class not registered" error.

Comment: @PhilJollans I have Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 and Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.15.0. So it's no surprise why Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0 didn't work.